# How to move a localhost wordpress site to already registered wordpress domain

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have built a wordpress site locally. Now I want to host the site globally .
I already have bought a wordpress blog domain (i.e. It changed the site name from xyz.wordpress.com to xyz.org )
Now how I can transfer my local plugins and themes to xyz.org ??

Comment: What about the hosting ?

Comment: You mean I have to host it separately ??? like goDaddy or some other servers?right?

Comment: yes,,  read through https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Answer (score 1):

1. Move all files with wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes into  your host.
2. Delete wp-config.php file.
3. Go to site URL EX: example.com and go through typical installation procedure.
4. Go to your database in your host and delete those 11 tables which have made.
5. Now you should export the local database and you should open it in any text editor and search and replace your local URL with new one.

Ex: localhost with example.com,  then import it to your database of real server.

Now It should work.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to go through these steps

1) Make a zip of your wordpress folder and upload to your domain.

2) Export your local database..Open it in any editor which has find and replace.now search for your local server name and replace it with your domain..For eg  find this xyz.wordpress.com  and replace with xyz.org in entire database

3) upload your database to live make changes in config file your db name ,username,pass

and you are live now

OR 
check these tutorials for reference

1) http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Comment: Thanks a lot . . . so basically to make a site xyz.org in wordpress we need to do 2 things? changing the name from xyz.wordpress.com to xyz.org through wordpress and host it somewhere else ???

Comment: You need to change the name in database..and then you can host it on live.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress.org provides the open source code for WordPress that you can run on your own website, with whatever plugins you choose.

WordPress.com provides (free) WordPress hosting, but you are limited as to what plugins and configurations you can make to your site.

[read more about](https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)