# moving wordpress website and database

Tags: database, wordpress

I made wp website on my testing domain. I would like now to move it to local mamp server.

I have tried using updraftplus plugin, but it didn't work (website is constantly refreshing, sort of being in a loop).

Now I want to move it manually. I have downloaded whole website through ftp and I also exported db.

I made new dbd with same name on my mamp server/phpadmin. In wp-cofig the database, username, password are the same as in my testing page. however local site can't connect to db that I have imported (I have used the same name for database on local machine).

I have read several instructions how to do this, but now I'm lost.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you got ?

Comment: I always get "Error establishing a database connection". I have tried to change the settings in wp-config.php (in database I have added a new user as well with all privileges, but that didn't solve the problem). I know that I'm doing something wrong with importing database (and connecting to it)

Comment: did you search and replace your previous base URL with new URL in your SQL file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803922/how-to-move-a-localhost-wordpress-site-to-already-registered-wordpress-domain/35051454#35051454)

Did you use the same table prefix as you  used in previous one.
and Don't Forget to Change your previous base URL to new local URL in each and every place in your SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

find wp_options in database and change site url and home url from your testing domain to localhost

Comment: I changed already the url to localhost, still not working. are there some more url's that I have to change (I know for wp_option)